# Limiting the column data width to fixed size in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fixed-length-record

I am using Bootstrap 3 responsive tables for showing the data.
However, One of column is having huge data compare to rest of the columns as shown below

[image]

But I would like to display **limited length** of description.
In short, `I would like to display first 2 to 3 lines of data [or 300 characters] and followed by .....`

If possible, hovering over the description column should show complete description as `tooltip`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is it really a bootstrap 3 problem ? I think you should do a substring  of your data to get 300 chars, wrap in a span, with an title[|| popover||tooltip] attribute with your full description.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set up maximum height on Table row and then Use CSS ellipsis property to show trim data (No JS/Jquery required).

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

It will trim when data overloads the table row and show dots automatically. You can show full data on tool tip just wrapping your data or view more with tool tip. You can thank me by accepting answer.

CSS:

apply a class mytable on  tag and use this css:

```
.mytable tbody tr td{
  max-width:200px; /* Customise it accordingly */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: sorry I am not much into UI development. Any working example please? :)

Comment: I tried something like this  <td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;" class="ellipses">${record.attributes.P_Description}</td>


.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;  
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;  
}

but didn't work

Comment: that's great and it's working. But any idea, how do I show tooltip with full information.

Comment: Use bootstrap default tooltip or popover and load all the content in that and use a link to display that or you can write js code to show it on hover.

Comment: I added class="iffyTip" to the td and then added the following javascript to the bottom of the page to add tooltips containing the full text. --

    //show tooltip if content is truncated 
    $(document).on('mouseenter', ".iffyTip", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth && !$this.attr('title')) {
            $this.tooltip({
                container: "body",
                title: $this.text(),
                placement: "bottom"
            });
            $this.tooltip('show');
        }
    });

Comment: @Reddy ellipses != ellipsis

Answer (score 1):

Put your text in `$string` variable, then use:

```
$short_string = (strlen($string) > 300) ? substr($string,0,300) : $string;
```

This will check your text and if it's over 300 character then this will give you the first 300 characters.
Or use this code to add '...' at the end of your new short string.

```
$short_string = (strlen($string) > 300) ? substr($string,0,300).'...' : $string;
```

Comment: Will not allow you to display whole text as a hint for example. But I don't know why someone downvote?